# Wpf Show underneath blurry

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blur

In wpf how can I make controls underneath a transparent control blurry like windows Aero?
I need this for my custom modal windows with a border in outside for locking mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pixel shader effects](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2008/10/06/wpf-shader-effects-library-posted/) to mimic that effect. [Here](http://shazzam-tool.com/) is a tool for building/testing pixel shaders.

Comment: Isn't there something built-in in PresentationFramework.Aero? I regularly use DropShadowClone for example: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/a-lightweight-alternative-to-dropshadowbitmapeffect/ and was wondering if there were any tool to perform this operation included in this assembly

Comment: @Damascus - not to replicate the glass look, no. That's part of the Vista/Win7 [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx). You can certainly create Windows that have glass that extends the entire window, like shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx). Not sure that's what you were going for though.